# Open set as a countable union of closed balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. For every $x\in U$ we can find, due to the density of rationals, a pair $(p,r)\in\mathbb{Q}^n \times\mathbb{Q}^+$ such that $x\in B(p,r) \subset U$. Apparently this is enough to show that every open set is a countable union of open balls? On the otherhand, there surely exists such a pair $(p,r)$ that $x \in B(p,r) \subset \overline{B}(p,r) \subset U$. Is that enough to show that every open set is a countable union of closed balls? (This might be trivial but I haven't found a reference.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Should be $(p,r)\in\mathbb Q^n\times \mathbb Q^+.$ Note $\in$ versus your $\subset,$ and $\mathbb Q^+,$ which keeps the ball from being empty or a single point.

Comment: Being a countable union of closed balls is also true, but closed balls are neither a basis for $\mathbb R^n,$ since they aren’t open, nor some kind of co-basis (the equivalent of a basis for closed sets.) So we can observe this, but it is not very important. The reason for the theorem is showing $\mathbb R^n$ has a countable basis, and a basis consists of open sets, by definition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It proves that every open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is $\sigma$-compact.